# In packer, how do I add the literal braces {{}} in a string without calling a function?

Tags: packer

Ansible supports a `{{CWD}}` macro.

Packer uses `{{}}` for functions and variables.

I don't see any way to escape the `{{function_name}}` syntax so that I can put in a literal `{{CWD}}`. I've tried a bunch of different things including using unicode braces (did not work), but they always end up being invalid or trying to call a non-existent CWD function which obviously breaks packer.

This is an example of a string I'm trying to get to work.

`"extra_arguments": [ "--extra-vars", "roles_path={{.CWD}}/temp-roles" ],`

I found a hacky workaround. Just grab the $PWD variable provided by the shell and pass it in, then use that in place where I'd used the CWD. This does NOT answer my question, and looking at the Go template library this is based on I don't think it's possible to escape the curly braces.

```
  "variables": {
    "pwd": "{{env `PWD`}}"
  },

      "extra_arguments": [ "--extra-vars", "roles_path={{user `pwd`}}/temp-roles" ],
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a variable, e.g. `"VAR" : "roles_path={{.CWD}}/temp-roles"`, then referencing it as `"extra_arguments": [ "--extra-vars", "{{user \`VAR\`}}" ]` ?

Comment: You put .CWD which means "the value of the variable CWD" which is not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to pass in the literal string {{CWD}} so that ansible can interpolate it. In your provided example packer will explode because .CWD isn't a defined variable.

Comment: I see, thought you wanted it literally and not evaluated.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I did want it literally, but I think that's impossible with the templating engine packer is using under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is impossible with the go templating engine that packer uses under the hood. I've opened a ticket with them, but since they're trying to move to HCL I don't know if this will ever be fixed.

https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9125